# Understanding the Haskell type of this expression

Tags: haskell

I was doing a Haskell types exercise and this one has stumped me. The provided expression is:

```
f2 f g h = h.g.f
```

And the type for f2 is apparently:

```
f2 :: (a -> b1) -> (b1 -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
```

This seems overly complicated for such a short expression. Can someone explain why this makes sense as the type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think it's complicated? It's just a function that takes three functions (of matching types) and returns a new one.

I've renamed `b1` to `b` and updated other names, for consistency. So here is a slightly edited version:

> `f2 :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (c -> d) -> a -> d`

- Here, `f2` takes `f` which has type `a -> b`. Meaning, it's a function, with some input of some type `a` (`a` can be just anything, no restrictions here) and some return value of type `b`.
- Then `f2` takes `g` which input's type must match `f`'s output, so it's `b -> c`. It cannot be, like, `e -> c` (where `e` is something different from `b`), or the code won't make sense as it won't be possible to compose `f . g`.
- And exactly the same goes for the third argument, `h`, with type `c -> d`.
- The result of function composition (what `f2` returns) is a new function that takes in whatever `f` does and returns whatever `h` returns, so it's `a -> d`. With this we've covered the whole type definition.

Basically, it's a relatively long definition, but I think it's of a very simple nature.

Comment: The 4th point is what is confusing me, I understand up until there. Specifically I don't get "takes in whatever f does and returns whatever h returns,"

Comment: Okay I stared at it a little longer and I now understand why d, or c in the example I gave, would be there but I'm still a bit confused about why a has to be there.

Comment: @KaiD: consider a slightly simpler example `f3 f g = f . g`, which would have a type `f3 :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c`. It takes two functions (`f` and `g`), and produces a new one. In the `a -> c` part, it says that the input type of the produced function will be `a` - the same type that `f` takes in. And the return type is `d`, the same as `g` returns. For example, if `f` takes a string and returns an integer, and `g` takes an integer and returns a boolean then the result of `f3` must take a string and return a boolean - this is what the type declaration says. Makes sense?

Comment: @KaiD because with a function composition, your result type is a function. `d` (`c` in your example) is only a result type of that function.

Comment: @KaiD Just a suggestion. Check out http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions. It's about the same stuff (functions, taking functions and returning other functions) so the explanations and examples from there may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 3):

I find these “determine the type of such and such expression” generally a bit backwards. Types should always come first: you want to program a solution to some task, you formulate the problem description as a type signature. *Then* you go ahead and actually write an implementation.

In this case, you'd start with the problem: I have three functions `f`, `g` and `h`, and a value of type that I can pass to `f`. Furthermore, the functions have pairwise matching result/argument type. Hence the signature

```
f2 :: (α -> β) -> (β -> γ) -> (γ -> δ) -> α -> δ
```

You could now go on and implement this in explicit-pointed form, i.e.

```
f2 f g h x = h (g (f x))
```

which is still quite brief. After all, it's quite a simple task!

But in Haskell you can make it even shorter, by using the standard composition operator `.`. The fact that the final implementation is so extremely short is basically just down to the fact that `f2` does essentially the same thing as `.`, just twice. So this isn't more surprising than if you have a very complex task with a complicated type signature, but discover some library that contains a function which does almost that exact task. Obviously, invoking that ready-build function will give you a much shorter implementation than the task complexity would suggest, but the complexity is merely deferred to the library function.

Comment: I'm with you up to what would be the equivalent to (b -> c) in my question but I don't understand why the type expression doesn't just end there. Why do I need to the next two, in my case -> a -> c ?

Comment: @KaiD because type expressions cover return values. `a -> c` (`α -> δ`) is a type of what `f2` returns.